# ASP.Net C# JavaScript Popup Window Help

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I've looked all over the place and had very little luck.

```
try{
FooError();
}
catch (Exception Exc){              
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "errorPop",
@"<script language='javascript'> alert(" + Exc.Message + "); </script>");
return;
}
```

I keep getting a javascript error saying "Expected a ')'.". I've tried the script with a @ at the start (like it is), without a @ at the start, with and without a semicolon at the end. I've tried

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "errorPop",
@"<script type=\"text/javascript\"> alert(" + Exc.Message + "); </script>");
```

I've been able to get this to work with a static value in the alert function

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "errorPop",
@"<script language='javascript'> alert('Foo'); </script>");
```

But that's not what I need.
What am I doing wrong here? Is there a better way?
I guess what I mean to ask is how do you use a C# string variable in a JavaScript alert box, if it's even possible.

Thanks.

This is my first question I hope I did it right -.-;

Comment: Problem solved. It was with the variable. For dealing with Alert(string <var>), <var> must be in the form "'Stuff'".

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there may be some characters in your Exc.Message that break the javascript string.  Look at your source to see what's generated, but I'd expect to find something like this:

```
<script language='javascript'> alert("Error "this" happened"); </script>
```

Notice how the "this" would break that.  So you'd need to do something like

```
Exc.Message.Replace("\"", "'");
```

Comment: Hadn't thought of that. error message currently being passed is: "Ticket No. Field is blank or has an invalid entry. Field must have an integer value.". It's a string literal so... it shouldn't include the "" when it gets evaluated? Not sure...

Comment: Well, the only way to be sure sure is to view source and see what's generated.  It may not be the " character, that was just an example.  Once you find it, you can escape it.

Answer (score 0):

add quotes around the Exc.Message -- like you did with Foo.

```
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "errorPop",
@"<script type=\"text/javascript\"> alert('" + Exc.Message + "'); </script>");
```

or

```
 ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "errorPop",
    @"<script type=\"text/javascript\"> alert(\"" + Exc.Message + "\"); </script>");
```

Because your output would look like this

```
alert(whatever the message is);
```

Comment: Tried this but now it's... being weird. ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "errorPop",
     @"<script language='javascript'> alert("' + Exc.Message + '"); </script>"); under red squiggly "you're doing it wrong" indicator its saying that it's expecting things that are there, a semicolon, a closing ), just behaving oddly.

Comment: Your IDE is probably seeing the javascript and getting confused.

Comment: sorry i'm used to enter=newline not enter=submit -.-;

Comment: It might be easier to put the javascript part into a variable, at least while debugging so you can see what's happening.

Comment: how do you mean? string var bla = "<script.../script>"?

Comment: yeah, just add a line ahead of this one, like....

string theJavascript=@"<script type.... etc.

then you can put a breakpoint after that and check out the value of theJavascript.

Comment: It's probably not affecting anything, but it's also a good idea to wrap Exc.Message in Server.HtmlEncode to escape any characters....................... Server.HtmlEncode(Exc.Message) -- unless the message is yours so you can trust it and ignore this whole comment.

Comment: You can't mix @" with \", only use one or the other.